# Where should I store my window dimensions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am popping up various Telerik RadWindows of different sizes based on the types of items that are selected.  Each type of item has its own kind of edit form that pops up when clicked, so I need to set different heights and widths of the window in Javascript.  Right now I'm using this function which has the dimensions for each type hard-coded:

```
 function GetEditWindowDimensions(type) {
        var dimensions = null;           
        switch (type) {
            case 'Type1':
                dimensions = { length: 330, width: 400 };
                break
            case 'Type2':     
                dimensions = { length: 550, width: 450 };
                break;
            case 'Type2':
                dimensions = { length: 260, width: 400 };
                break;    
            case 'Type3':    
                dimensions = { length: 260, width: 400 };
                break;
            case 'Type4':
                dimensions = { length: 260, width: 400 };
                break;
            case 'Type5':
                dimensions = { length: 330, width: 400 };
                break;
            default:
                dimensions = { length: 500, width: 500 };

        }
        return dimensions
    }
```

And here is my function to load the RadWindow:

```
   function OpenEditWindow(type) {

        var oDimensions = GetEditWindowDimensions(type)
        var oWindow = openWindow('myurl.aspx', oDimensions.length, oDimensions.width, true);

        oWindow.MoveTo(200, 25);
    }
```

There has got to be a nicer way to do this. Do you have any ideas on how I could store/retrieve these dimensions in a configurable way in Javascript? The types themselves are defined by an enum in a .vb file in the project. I pass the enum value name to GetEditWindowDimensions().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! Was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store them like this:

```
dimensions = {
    Type1: {
        length: 330,
        width: 400
    },
    ...
    ...
    Type5:  {
        length: 330,
        width: 400
    }
};
```

Then you can access them by doing `dimensions.Type1` or `dimensions[type]` if you're looking them up dynamically. For the default case, just check to see if the dimension you're trying to access is `undefined`. If it is, use the default length and width. For example:

```
var dimension = dimensions[type];
if(typeof dimension === "undefined") {
    dimension = {
        length: 500,
        width: 500 
    };
}
```

or more succinct:

```
var dimension = dimensions[type] || {length: 500, width: 500};
```

This will use second value (the one after the `||`) if the first value is not "truthy".

Answer (score 2):

You could just store it in an object like:

```
    var dimensions = {
        'Type1': { length: 330, width: 400 },
        'Type2': { length: 550, width: 450 },
        'Type3': { length: 260, width: 400 }
    }
```

Then access them like

```
dimensions.type1.length; // <-- 330
dimensions.type1.width; // <-- 400
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a hash?

```
var dWindowDimensions = }
    Type1: { length: 330, width: 400 },
    Type2: { length: 550, width: 450 },
    ...
}
```

Then, when you need to read the values:

```
var oDimensions = dWindowDimensions[type]
```